# asyncData lifecycle doesn't work in Nuxt & Vue correctly

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I wanna get data by `AsyncData` lifecycle to fetch that server side, `Axios doesn't work inside AsyncData` so data items don't rewrite.

any ideas to solve that? regards.

```
<template>
   <div>
       <div> messages: {{ messages }} </div>
       <div> enable: {{ enable }} </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      messages: '',
      enable: false
     }
   }
  mounted (){
   // Something.......
  },
  async asyncData () {
        await this.axios.get('sample url') 
         .then(({result}) => {
            let value = JSON.parse(result.value);
            return {
                messages: value.messages,
                enable: value.enable,
            };
        });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't return anything from asyncdata. It should be either return a promise or awaiting data and return it

```
asyncData () {
        return this.axios.get('sample url') 
         .then(({result}) => {
            let value = JSON.parse(result.value);
            return {
                messages: value.messages,
                enable: value.enable,
            };
        });
    }
```